# Set up page height in JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Can i set page height for report(generated by iReport) by passing its size from Java source,(passing parameters???). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`setPageHeight`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperPrint.html#setPageHeight%28int%29) on your `JasperPrint` object. The documentation says that it

> Sets the page height.